# php/mysql Data Id into header table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As newbie on PHP/MySQL.

I work the PHP/MySql on the last three weeks, and it's coming together great but it's a massive learning curving from Mysql data into php.

The question I'am trying get data Id into Header as table but somehow it won't work and it's keep not displayed at all or error.

Like all 'Transaction type' goes to header or TR, then 'each group amount' goes to table body or TD

Here is a code

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover dt-responsove wrap" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
        <th  Class="table-header-total">
            <?php
               while (($grouptotalrow = mysqli_fetch_array($grouptotalorder1, MYSQLI_BOTH)) != NULL) {
                ?>  
               <td  class="table-smaller-text-bolder"><?php echo $grouptotalrow["transaction_type"];?></th>
                <?php
                }
                mysqli_free_result($grouptotalorder1);
            ?>    
            <?php
               while (($grouptotalrow = mysqli_fetch_array($grouptotalorder, MYSQLI_BOTH)) != NULL) {
                ?>  
               <td  class="table-smaller-text-bolder"><?php echo $grouptotalrow["Each_group_Amount"];?></td>
                <?php
                }
                mysqli_free_result($grouptotalorder);
            ?>    
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a Database

```
SELECT 
    settlement_id,
    total_amount,
    transaction_type,
    amount_description,
    SUM(amount) AS `Each_group_Amount`
FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    transaction_type = 'order'
        OR transaction_type = 'Refund'
        OR transaction_type = 'ServiceFee'
        OR transaction_type = 'other-transaction'
        OR transaction_type = ''

GROUP BY settlement_id ASC , amount_description ASC
```

[Screenshot of mysql workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7aeE.png)

this result is not what I'mm looking for

[Result in webpages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lQRA.png)

Comment: table header tag is <th></th>

Comment: Done change td to th ( that's my mistake and i overlook it) but sadly this issue is still same as i rewrite it.

Comment: *what* kind of issue?

Comment: as you can see it http://amazonsettlement.ishka.ie/fortnight_settlement_breakdown.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I have decided to give myself a break from PC/PHP stuff for a few hours (more like clear on my head) and come back and finally, I got it fixed.

Here is a code as I wrote

```
<?php

            echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover dt-responsove wrap" cellspacing="0">';
            echo '<tbody>';
            echo '<tr>Break down of transation sale</tr>';
            $resultTranactiontypegroup = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlbreakdowntransaction_type);
            while (($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultTranactiontypegroup, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL) {

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th class="table-header-total">' . $row1['transaction_type'] . '</th>';
                echo '<td class="table-smaller-text">' . $row1['Each_group_Amount'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            mysqli_free_result($resultTranactiontypegroup);
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>'
            ?>
```